# Network disconnecting and connecting randomly

Tags: linux, network-interface, networkmanager

When I’m working on the computer the network sometimes disconnects and connects again multiple times. This happens irregularly and I cannot reproduce it. Does anyone have an idea how I could approach this problem?

Here the hardware info:

```
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Ethernet I219-LM vendor: Holco Enterprise Co /Shuttle
    driver: e1000e v: kernel port: N/A bus-ID: 00:1f.6
  IF: eth1 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Intel Ethernet I225-V vendor: Holco Enterprise Co /Shuttle
    driver: igc v: kernel port: N/A bus-ID: 01:00.0
  IF: eth0 state: up speed: 2500 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>

# nmcli device show
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         80:EE:73:FA:CF:22
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     eth0
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnecti>
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.106/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.1.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
IP4.SEARCHES[1]:                        shuttle
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2a02:1210:7489:a300:2697:710a:426:426d/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         2a02:1210:7489:a300:e284:205d:22b6:9db1/64
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         fe80::1744:cadf:be2:4aee/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::a6ce:daff:feb7:b0a0
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 2a02:1210:7489:a300::/64, nh = ::, mt = >
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = fe80::a6ce:daff:feb7:b0a0, mt>
IP6.DNS[1]:                             2a02:1210:7489:a300::1
IP6.SEARCHES[1]:                        home

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         80:EE:73:FA:CF:21
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ::1/128, nh = ::, mt = 256
```

And here the output from the log:

```
# journalctl -u NetworkManager -f
Dec 06 09:11:46 sh NetworkManager[919]: <info>  [1701850306.1141] device (eth0): carrier: link connected
Dec 06 09:11:46 sh NetworkManager[919]: <info>  [1701850306.1143] device (eth0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'carrier-changed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 06 09:11:46 sh NetworkManager[919]: <info>  [1701850306.1151] policy: auto-activating connection 'eth0' (7ba00b1d-8cdd-30da-91ad-bb83ed4f7474)
Dec 06 09:11:46 sh NetworkManager[919]: <info>  [1701850306.1156] device (eth0): Activation: starting connection 'eth0' (7ba00b1d-8cdd-30da-91ad-bb83ed4f7474)
Dec 06 09:11:46 sh NetworkManager[919]: <info>  [1701850306.1157] device (eth0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 06 09:11:46 sh NetworkManager[919]: <info>  [1701850306.1158] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Dec 06 09:11:46 sh NetworkManager[919]: <info>  [1701850306.1160] device (eth0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 06 09:11:46 sh NetworkManager[919]: <info>  [1701850306.1356] device (eth0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 06 09:11:46 sh NetworkManager[919]: <info>  [1701850306.1362] policy: set 'eth0' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Dec 06 09:11:46 sh NetworkManager[919]: <info>  [1701850306.2509] device (eth0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 06 09:11:46 sh NetworkManager[919]: <info>  [1701850306.2598] device (eth0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 06 09:11:46 sh NetworkManager[919]: <info>  [1701850306.2600] device (eth0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Dec 06 09:11:46 sh NetworkManager[919]: <info>  [1701850306.2604] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Dec 06 09:11:46 sh NetworkManager[919]: <info>  [1701850306.2606] device (eth0): Activation: successful, device activated.
```

So far I tried:

- Replacing all cables
- Replacing the switch
- Reinstalling the whole system
- Switching off IPV6
  but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1):

Your `eth0` interface is an Intel I225-V. If you google for it, you will find a lot of vitriolic discussion about it.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000057261/ethernet-products/gigabit-ethernet-controllers-up-to-2-5gbe.html

https://community.intel.com/t5/Ethernet-Products/Intel-I225-V-Drops-Connections/m-p/1474748

There seems to have been a large batch of Intel I225-V chips with a hardware bug. Apparently the motherboard manufacturers that received most of that batch were Asus and Gigabyte, but other manufacturers may have received some buggy chips too.

The initial revision of the chip did require a 8-byte inter-packet gap on 2.5G speed, instead of the 5-byte gap allowed by the specification. This will cause dropped packets and renegotiating the link at 1-gigabit speed. The repeated renegotiations can cause a massive slowdown. See official errata from Intel: https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getContent/621661

The subsequent revisions attempted to fix the problem, but apparently did not get it quite right the first time, or something else broke as a result of the first fix.

Since your I225-V is apparently integrated to the motherboard (as indicated by `vendor: Holco Enterprise Co /Shuttle`), see if your system/motherboard vendor has provided firmware updates, either in the form of a BIOS update, or as a separate NIC firmware update.

Apparently the firmware workarounds may require motherboard-model-specific tweaking, so you should prefer firmware from your specific motherboard/system vendor over generic ones.

However, if you have one of the buggy chip revisions, the firmware workaround may not be able to achieve a stable 2.5G link, but instead will make the card switch more persistently down to a 1G link which should then stay stable regardless of the hardware bug.

Apparently the chip version B3 is (mostly?) usable, and older versions are problematic in various ways.

Comment: I updated the BIOS to the latest version and so far the network had no interruptions. but it sometimes takes certain time before it happens. I will observe it and report.

Comment: I happened again. Unfortunately the BIOS update didn't change anything.